# Creating user throws TypeError

Tags: django

When trying to `createsuperuser` django throws:

```
NOTIMPORTANT/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py", line 26, in get_password_validators
    klass = import_string(validator['NAME'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

All my `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` in `settings.py` are commented out.
It happend when I migrated my project onto production, no longer in development but I don't want anny password validators.

Comment: Please, post the commented AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS. Since this is where the error is, we need to see it.

Comment: I completely cleaned the inside, not only commented it. It fixed the problem, so thanks for locating my issue.